# Detect you're done reading rows

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using a custom read filter to read files in chunks:

```
class chunkReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter{
    private $start_row, $end_row, $chunk_size;

    public function __construct($chunk_size, $start_row=1){
        $this->chunk_size = $chunk_size;
        $this->start_row = $start_row;
        $this->end_row = $start_row+$chunk_size-1;
    }

    public function moveCursor(){
        $this->start_row += $this->chunk_size;
        $this->end_row += $this->chunk_size;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = ''){
        return $row>=$this->start_row && $row<=$this->end_row;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure about know how to detect I've finished. Examples and documentation always hard-code a maximum row:

```
for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 65536; $startRow += $chunkSize) { 
}
```

The `PHPExcel_Worksheet::getHighestRow()` and `PHPExcel_Worksheet::getHighestDataRow()` methods seem to work on filtered data (kind of). For instance, in a 200 row file:

- If I read rows from 100 to 120 I get `120`
- If I attempt to read rows from 300 to 320 I get `1` :-?

What's the best way to stop the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to stop the loop is to know how many rows you should be reading in the first place.

There is a helper method in every Reader that will provide some basic meta data about the file without needing to load it all.

Before starting your loop:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$worksheetData = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($inputFileName);

echo '<h3>Worksheet Information</h3>';
echo '<ol>';
foreach ($worksheetData as $worksheet) {
    echo '<li>', $worksheet['worksheetName'], '<br />';
    echo 'Rows: ', $worksheet['totalRows'], 
        ' Columns: ', $worksheet['totalColumns'], '<br />';
    echo 'Cell Range: A1:', 
        $worksheet['lastColumnLetter'], $worksheet['totalRows'];
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

This is documented in section 7 of the User documentation for Reading Spreadsheet files, and in `Examples/Reader/exampleReader19.php`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to loop thoughout cells is using `getRowIterator` and `getCellIterator`:

```
$rows  = $sheet->getRowIterator();
foreach ($rows as $r => $row) {
    $cells = $row->getCellIterator();
    foreach ($cells as $c => $cell) {
         $value = $cell->getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you mean that when those iterators don't yield anything, you're done. Sorry, it doesn't work. You always get something, even if you're far from the last row with data.

Comment: There's no way to prevent that. If you set something on a field and then you remove it (the content), then the phpexcel reader will detect that row as filled. The only thing you can do is check if the value is an expected value; if not, then you should skip it.

Comment: Do you mean that you always need to read chunks until you reach the maximum row limit, which is 65,536 in Excel 2003 and 1,048,576 in Excel 2010?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that all the methods given by PHPExcel to know the latest row/cell return exactly the same. And this includes rows with empty content (rows that were previously filled and thus content removed).

So, from my experience, what I suggest you is using one of their methods (that won't return the maximum row limit unless you have data on it) and check every field to verify its content.